# Uncaught Type Error p = l.Db(f) Open Layer 4.6.4

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geowebcache

I have searched everywhere but I have not found any results.

Currently I am trying to load a **Vector Tile layer with MVT format** hosted by **geoserver** using **OpenLayers 4.6.4**. When creating the map, I get a **"Uncaught TypeError: l.Db is not a function"** and the map does not appear.

```
    this.tileLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  declutter: true,
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
     format: new ol.format.MVT(),
     url: `https://domain.com/geowebcache/service/tms/1.0.0/OpenMapTiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`,
   })
});
this.map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [this.tileLayer],
    target: targetId,
    view: this.view,
  controls : ol.control.defaults({
    attribution : false,
    zoom : false,
  })
});
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I could not find an example anywhere on how to accomplish this. Turns out I had to create a tile grid and give it a tile-pixel ratio.

Here is my code:

```
  var t_tilegrid = ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({tileSize: 512, maxZoom: 22});
   var t_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
     source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
       attributions: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
         '© <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
         'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
       format: new ol.format.MVT(),
       tileGrid: t_tilegrid,
       tilePixelRatio: 8,
       url: geo_web_cache.url,
     })
   });
```